# Microsoft Graph SDK .NET get events in range

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I tried to get all the events in a certain range using the following code

```
DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Parse("2018-07-20T11:00:00"), dateEnd = dateStart.AddDays(1);

List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("startDateTime", dateStart.ToUniversalTime().ToString()),
    new QueryOption("endDateTime", dateEnd.ToUniversalTime().ToString())
};

var eventsInRange = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events.Request(options).GetAsync();
```

But it returns the events in all history, not only in range. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the [`/events`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) endpoint using [`/calendarView`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) parameters. You want to use the `CalendarView` class:

```
var eventsInRange = await graphClient.Me
    .Calendar
    .CalendarView
    .Request(options)
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Could you please mark this question as answered so future users can easily find the same solution?