# Microsoft Graph SDK .NET get group events in range

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get events of a group calendar within a specific range. Already found this post:

[Microsoft Graph SDK .NET get events in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526017/microsoft-graph-sdk-net-get-events-in-range)

Then tried to adopt the code provided in the above post to fit my needs:

```
DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Parse("2019-13-06T00:00:00"), dateEnd = dateStart.AddDays(30);

List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("startDateTime", dateStart.ToUniversalTime().ToString()),
    new QueryOption("endDateTime", dateEnd.ToUniversalTime().ToString())
};

var eventsInRange = await graphClient.Groups[groupId]
                                     .Calendar
                                     .CalendarView
                                     .Request(options)
                                     .GetAsync();
```

The result was, that `eventsInRange` was not null but the resultset of events did not contain any element.

There are events in the specific calendar and I get them when using this code:

```
events = await graphClient.Groups[groupId]
                          .Calendar
                          .Events
                          .Request()
                          .GetAsync();
```

Did not find a lot of information about that in the official microsoft documentation. So it's hard to guess what I did wrong.

Would be great if anyone has some helpful idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself and this is what I found out. Maybe it will be helpful for someone else too:

This code was inside of a try-catch-block and therefore I got no exception during debugging as long as I put a breakpoint into the catch block. That showed me an error pointing to a missformatted datetime string.

What solved the problem was an additional formatstring for the ToString() method:

```
new QueryOption("startDateTime", dateStart.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of permission have you set up in App Registration? I set up for Calender.ReadWrite and Group.Read it won't allow me to get events in one specific group.

```
Status Code: Forbidden Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: AppOnlyAccessNotEnabledForTarget Message: App Only access is not allowed for target resource:"xxxxxxxxxxxx".
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34703600)